# What does “second” mean here and why did Jamie used it here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is from Jamie Dimon interview in Stanford:

> Character is a sine qua non and by character I also mean that they tell the whole truth, nothing but the truth. They do not shape the truth and they say the same thing to you and me. because **second** I see people doing something different than that you just go on a list to me, I have no interest. “

So why he did not say just when instead of second? I am also not able to find the meaning of “you just go on a list to me”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He means "the second I see" - he could have said "the minute" or "the moment" - using "the second" suggests that his response is very quick (some people say "the microsecond" suggesting an even quicker - and physiologically impossible - reaction speed).

He quite likely said "the second" but "the" was very quick.

Comment: so the second is very quick while if he used when it would mean he is not saying it so quick?

Comment: Yes. It means the same as "when", but emphasises the speed of his reaction - almost certainly as hyperbole. He probably doesn't react particularly quickly, but wants to suggest that he is so keen to react that way that he reacts instantly.